# Sample N Tier Windows Forms Application - C#.NET

Tags: winforms

I am new to .NET Windows Forms Applications.

Would you please let me know if there is any sample ’N Tier Windows Forms Application’ built on C#.NET so that I could go through it and understand the concepts?

It would be of great help  to me.

Many thanks.

Regards,
Reshma.

Comment: C# and N-Tier aren't the same thing. There are .Net libraries that can help construct such a beast.  Be sure you're fluent in both N-Tier architectures OR the programming language before trying to tackle both at once.

Answer (score 2):

You canstart at the [MSDN C# code samples topics page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287464%28VS.71%29.aspx) and branch out from there.